# Windows 11 Audio Volume jumps a large amount when changing apps

Tags: windows-11

The volume changes without me doing anything that *should* change the volume. It usually happens when I launch or switch apps, but I have noticed it happening spontaneously on occasion.

This occurs more often with Windows apps, such as Minecraft (Minecraft will trigger it almost every time I launch the app, and almost every time tab out and then back). No solutions I've found so far have helped, nor any that I thought of myself. The volume gets painfully loud; it is a very big increase from like 20% to like 95%.

If I try to activate the app I want to use enough times, it will eventually not do this. But it happens very frequently, so I have to open the volume settings and try re-activating my app multiple times. Tabbing out is quite needed for using the wiki or multitasking and so on.

It happens with more than one headset. This has been happening for at least 6 months, probably more. Changing the default sound device doesn't help. Setting the monitor sound to a low amount (my monitor has very bad speakers: I have to turn the monitor volume high) does not help.

- I haven't tried rolling back the audio driver.
- I have tried checking for updates for audio driver.
- Windows is fully updated, and I haven't tried rolling back windows update.
- There are no audio enhancements enabled on my system.
- No applications are taking exclusive control of my device.
- Windows is not set to adjust my volume based on communications activity.

Comment: Run driver updates for all drivers.  Uninstall gaming apps.  Restart, Install gaming apps and test.